# How to set my clickable banner to open in the same window?

Tags: internal, banner, clickable

I created a banner that links to one of the pages on my website, but when I click it, it opens in a new tab. How can I make it internal, opening in the same window?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `target` attribute of your link to `_self`. This is its default value and if you've not specified `target` attribute at all, it has to be opened in its own window. Here is an example:

```
<a href="www.google.com" target="_self">link text</a>
```

The `target` attribute specifies where to open the linked page.

For more information take a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) reference at [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com)